# Why is Gson unable to access Private fields like it's supposed to?

Tags: java, class, gson

I'm trying to use Gson to save a class (GameMap) as a JSON file. I have seen many people saying how it is supposed to read private fields, but only works for me if I make everything public, and otherwise gives this error:

```
public String toJson() {        
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    return gson.toJson(this);
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private application.Tile[][] application.GameMap.tiles accessible: module Comp_Sci_Final does not "opens application" to module com.google.gson

I have already exported application to com.google.gson.

```
module Comp_Sci_Final {
    requires com.google.gson;
    exports application to com.google.gson;
    exports tiles to com.google.gson;
}
```

Everything works when I make it public. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2):

`exports` only makes the public and protected types and members accessible. To allow Gson to access private fields using reflection you must use `opens`:

```java
module Comp_Sci_Final {
    requires com.google.gson;
    opens application to com.google.gson;
    opens tiles to com.google.gson;
}
```

See also [Java Language Specification §7.7.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7.2) and [Understanding Java 9 Modules](https://www.oracle.com/de/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).